# Setting Minimum TLS Version Micronaut HttpClient

Tags: ssl, https, micronaut, tls1.3

The documentation from Micronaut is limited here.

We're using `io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient` to access a 3rd party API.

All I can find is this https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html but it doesn't give examples.

How do we specify the version of TLS that we are prepared to interact with?

Answer (score 1):

To specify the version of TLS that you are prepared to interact with for io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient, you can use the sslContext property of the HttpClientConfiguration class.

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration;
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClientFactory;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

@Factory
public class MyHttpClientFactory {

    @Value("${my.http.client.url}")
    String url;

    @Singleton
    @Client("myClient")
    HttpClientConfiguration myClientConfig(HttpClientFactory factory) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        HttpClientConfiguration clientConfig = factory.createConfiguration(url);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        clientConfig.setSslContext(sslContext);
        return clientConfig;
    }
}
```

In this code, we create a factory class named MyHttpClientFactory that defines a myClientConfig method. This method creates a new HttpClientConfiguration instance and sets its sslContext property to use TLS version 1.2.

You can then use this factory class to create instances of io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient that are prepared to interact with servers using TLS version 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I have seen this before actually.. but how to achieve this with multiple TLS versions and also set the property globally for the default HttpClient instance instead of needing to do the above?